# detecting calls to outside PHP (curl, file get contents ...)

Tags: php, curl

Is there a simple way to detect all outside calls from PHP? 
In an open sourced project I have a lot of 3rd party scripts. With use of new relic I was able to debug long execution times leading back to some of this scripts making calls back to their servers.

I dont mind this but I want to know what data this scripts are sending and most of all I dont want to have slow site when 3rd party script server is down or not accessible.

Is there an easy way to log all curl, file get contents etc requests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for a packet sniffer. Usually you'll use `tcpdump` and/or `wireshark`.

- http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/tcpdump
- https://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions, but my preferred is

You build your own proxy : example a dedicated Apache Server (it can running in the same IP but different port who will handle this type of operations). After that, you change all of your old URL to pass by your proxy 
Imagine that you have this in your code :
 `curl_init('www.google.com');` 
so you have to change it by: 
`curl_init('http://localhost:8090/CALLS_OUTSIDE_PHP_CONTROLLER.php?url_to_redirect=www.google.com');`

The PHP controller running under 8090 can do many operations as : blacklist/whitelist some urls, doing regular URL check in background... many cool stuff

Comment: nice, but I dont have a list of all URLs ;) curl calls are sometimes even encoded so I cant simply search and replace